# Как передать в sql запрос переменную со слешем?

Tags: python, oracle

Мне нужно прочитать из файла данные и вставить их в базу данных. Но дело в том, что одна из колонок это номер операции, содержащие обратный слеш (пример: 1234\1). Питон сохраняет в переменную `opnumber` экранированный слеш и соответственно передает ее в sql запрос, из-за чего записи в бд неправильно пишутся.

```py
sql = """insert into table(opnumber,opdate,opsum) values (:opnumber,:opdate,:opsum)"""
```

Неправильный итоговый запрос:

```py
"insert into table(opnumber,opdate,opsum) values ('1234\\1','20.10.2020',277)"
```

Нужный запрос:

```py
"insert into table(opnumber,opdate,opsum) values ('1234\1','20.10.2020',277)"
```

Comment: `"insert into table(opnumber,opdate,opsum) values ('1234\\1','20.10.2020',277)"` - это строка, содержащая текст `insert into table(opnumber,opdate,opsum) values ('1234\1','20.10.2020',277)`. Если в базу неправильно пишется, значит проблема в чем-то другом. Покажите как именно вы видите, что в базу неправильно пишется.

Comment: каково изначальное значение переменных?

Comment: Перед вставкой обработайте вашу переменную `opnumber`. Замените \\ на \. Как то так это должно выглядеть `opnumber = opnumber.replace('\\\\', '\\');`

Comment: полагаю, что проблема у вас вероятнее всего не в сохранении информации (сохраняется, судя по всему, вполне корректно: скорее некорректным в unix-мире был бы одиночный обратный слэш — как его интерпретировать-то?), а в её отображении.